# Android passing unknown string to javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using Android to call JavaScript that takes in String parameter.

This works in normal case like below:

```
String statement = "Hello World!";
webview.loadUrl("javascript:echo('" + statement + "')");
```

Behind this interface is just a call to Android Toast API, this is nothing special.

Now, because I have no idea what String will be passing in to this "echo" function, I want to know if there is a way to ensure this JavaScript function will be executed no matter what String it received?

For instance, I want to input a single quote ('). In order for the JavaScript function to be called properly, I need to escape the quote with a backslash ().

There are numerous other characters that needs to be handled then.

Does anybody have an idea to how to come around this?

Comment: Did you solve this? How?

Answer (score -1):

It's not very clear why du you want to do this, but the quote is the only caracter to escape. So you could do :

```
statement = statement.replaceAll("'","\\'");
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear, single quote is not the only character I want to handle.

Comment: So, what else do you want to handle ?

Comment: There are numerous characters that when passed in to JavaScript that way, it just won't work. And I don't have a list for them. Thus, I am sourcing for a general way to handle this.

Comment: As a string, if you handle the simple quote, all other character inside the string will be handled as a character string... So, what are the so-mysterious "numerous-characters-you-dont-have-a-list-for-them" ???

Comment: Shouldn't you also replace back-slashes to double-back-slashes?

Comment: He's asking for a way to escape any string so it's securely handled by javascript without breaking the script, the character list is not important (nor mysterious).

Comment: Ok, sorry, I did not made myself clear : If he is working on a UTF-8 environment (html page I guess), then, there is nothing to escape. the only reason we need to escape the single quote is becaue it would break the echo('" + statement + "') into two pieces, due to the single quote enclosing.

Javascript is able to handle any characters, so thats why I was asking another example of character that i breaking the script...